# FlexeLint throws error on va_list

Tags: c, linux, variadic-functions

why FLexeLint throws error "**Warning 530: Symbol 'va' (line 23) not initialized**" on below code.

```
void debug(int msglevel, const char *fmt, ...)
{
va_list va;
va_start(va, fmt);
vfprintf(stderr, fmt, va);
va_end(va);
}
```

Is it necessary to initialize va_list?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary.  From the [man page for stdarg](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg):

> ```
> void va_start(va_list ap, last);
> ```
>
> The `va_start()` macro initializes ap for subsequent use by `va_arg()`
>   and `va_end()`, and must be called first.

Further, from section 7.16.1.4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *2* The `va_start` macro shall be invoked before any access to the unnamed arguments.
>
> *3* The `va_start` macro  initializes `ap` for  subsequent  use  by  the `va_arg` and `va_end` macros.  Neither the `va_start` nor
>   `va_copy` macro shall be invoked to reinitialize `ap` without an
>   intervening invocation of the `va_end` macro for the same `ap` .